# Assist with this matter, i cant seem to understand

Tags: c, declaration

```
int main()
{
    bool loop = true;
    while (loop)
    {
        loop = reservationCycle();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

i keep getting error: ‘reservationCycle’ was not declared in this scope

Comment: it's just not declared dude

Answer (score 1):

You havent declared the prototype of that function `reservationCycle()` It means the compiler doesnt know what reservationcycle is.. you should declare and define the whole function first before using it in main()